Download Failing for Images from Rich Text Area field from Email Message with "File Not Found" in Salesforce
I tried downloading an image in rich text area field in salesforce.
Email Message RTA Images
for custom objects we are able to download the images as suggested earlier by the Salesforce team ( documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm )
Here are the details :
How to recreate the scenario ?

In dev org create a rich text area field in Email Message .
enabling email to case service.
Create an email under case attach an image or file to the email body.
Go to that email message and add images to that RTA field created under
email message record.
Try downloading this RTA image based on documentation.

Note : We have a refid associated with the record (eid) but there is no image found.
RestAPI :
{{INSTANCE_URL}}/services/data/v{{version}}/sobjects/:SOBJECT_API_NAME/:RECORD_ID/richTextImageFields/:FIELD_NAME/:CONTENT_REFERENCE_ID
RECORDID : eid
CONTENT_REFERENCE_ID : refid




Please [edit] your question and include the text of the error message in the final screen shot -- this makes it easier for the Community to help you

Updated, i hope the issue is much clear than before.

doo you get same results (not found) on images associated with a RTF on Lead (like in the SFDC doc)?

@cropredy I am observing this behaviour only in EmailMessage  , in custom and in Lead i am able to download the image
